# AdMob Cordova not showing Ads banner in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob

I'm new in Cordova, I want to implement Ads in my Cordova application, I have made its demo, but I cannot see banner when I run my app.
I have follow this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-admob-simple
i have done same as this link. i showing my code :

```
function initAd(){
    if ( window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob ) {
        var ad_units = {
            ios : {
                banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx',
                interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx'
            },
            android : {
                banner: 'ca-app-pub-901042ds533264/4645275146',
                interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-9010443dsd64/4610326568'
            }
        };
        var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? ad_units.android : ad_units.ios;

        window.plugins.AdMob.setOptions( {
            publisherId: admobid.banner,
            interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,
            adSize: window.plugins.AdMob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER,  //use SMART_BANNER, BANNER, LARGE_BANNER, IAB_MRECT, IAB_BANNER, IAB_LEADERBOARD
            bannerAtTop: false, // set to true, to put banner at top
            overlap: true, // banner will overlap webview
            offsetTopBar: false, // set to true to avoid ios7 status bar overlap
            isTesting: true, // receiving test ad
            autoShow: true // auto show interstitial ad when loaded
        });

        registerAdEvents();
    } else {
        alert('admob plugin not ready');
    }

function registerAdEvents() {
    document.addEventListener('onReceiveAd', function(){});
    document.addEventListener('onFailedToReceiveAd', function(data){});
    document.addEventListener('onPresentAd', function(){});
    document.addEventListener('onDismissAd', function(){ });
    document.addEventListener('onLeaveToAd', function(){ });
    document.addEventListener('onReceiveInterstitialAd', function(){ });
    document.addEventListener('onPresentInterstitialAd', function(){ });
    document.addEventListener('onDismissInterstitialAd', function(){ });
}

function showBannerFunc(){
window.plugins.AdMob.createBannerView();}
function showInterstitialFunc(){
window.plugins.AdMob.createInterstitialView();  //get the interstitials ready to be shown and show when it's loaded.
window.plugins.AdMob.requestInterstitialAd();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your full code ? because I cannot see where you call those functions.

If you have a look at your fresh created project, in the file in `www/js/index.js` you should add a call to your functions in the `receivedEvent` function.

Have a look here on [this example](https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob/blob/master/Example/index.js), but if you copy paste it directly, ensure to add `app.initialize();` as the latest line (like in the `www/js/index.js` file).

Regards,
Benoit.